# ConcurrentModificationException when inserting data to Room Db

Tags: android

I'm basically try to save a volley response in my room db so I can later retrieve it for offline usage, but every time I start my app, I get this exception.

```
String api_keys = "MyApiKey" + awayid;

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, api_keys, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       JSONArray jsonArray2 = response.getJSONArray("teams");

                       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {

                           JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);

                           String awaylogo = jsonObject2.getString("strTeamBadge");

                           modelList.add(new Model(eventid,myround, date, hometeam, awayteam, homelogo, awaylogo, homescore, 
      awayscore, stadium, "Details", mytime));

                           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {

                                   ApplicationDatabase database = DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getApplicationDatabase();
                                                                        
                               database.modelDao().insert(modelList); /// here it is the problem in this line
        
                              }
                          }).start();
                      } 
                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }, error -> {});
```

*** This is my Dao

```
@Dao
public interface  modelDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Model ")
    List<Model> listAll();
    
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(List<Model> model);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a model object to my room db instead of list of model.

Answer (score 0):

Because you start lots of thread in your for loop.
Move your new thread after the for loop.

Comment: i moved the code just above catch exception and still getting the same error , i tried to move it out the volley request , no data is being saved , i dont know what wrong im doing

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying the data object anywhere while the data is being inserted to database? If that is the case, the error can be caused by paralell modification of same variable by different threads. Or this can be thrown even if you remove the contents from original array source while it is being inserted. Room insert operation is an async operation. If you are running the insertion using a Coroutine, you can get the completion in the invokeOnCompletion block. Otherwise if you really need to modify the object without waiting for completion, solution is pretty simple. You can copy the variable *modelList* to a new variable and use the new local variable as parameter to your insert call.

Eg:  (Kotlin)

```
val localCopy = modelList
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).feedDataDao().insertAll(localCopy).size

 }.invokeOnCompletion {
        Log.d("Inserted all items")
 }
```

Eg:  (Java)

```
List<MyDataType> localCopy = modelList       
AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).feedDataDao().insertAll(localCopy).size
```